# Why quantum mechanical degeneracy is unwanted?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, energy, angular-momentum, quantum-states, parity

Degeneracy arises when two or more distinguishable quantum states share something same, like energy or angular momentum.

Why physics always find for ways to remove this degeneracy?

Like external magnetic field removes energy degeneracy (Zeeman effect?).

Why is this removal of degeneracy important? Why a degenerate state is unwanted?

In how many ways (like energy, angular momentum, parity) we can get degeneracy?

Comment: I don't think that it is true in general that degeneracy is unwanted. There are any number of reasons why degeneracy might be a problem in a particular experiment or for a particular mathematical result, but those are case specific. There are many cases where degeneracy makes no difference, where it can be dealt with in a straightforward manner or where it may be helpful or necessary. If you want to know why degeneracy is a problem in the particular case you are looking at, you are going to need to tell us more details about that case (for which I would probably ask a new question)

Answer (score 1):

I've never seen degeneracy described as unwanted. Those degeneracies commonly are the result of symmetries, so they tend to be lifted when those symmetries are broken.

You mentioned the Zeeman effect, it's simply a magnetic field breaking the rotational invariance of an atom. There's nothing wanted or unwanted about that, it's just a phenomena among others.

As a teacher, however, I could favor symmetry-rich systems (hence, with degeneracies), as they usually make for nice introductory examples.

Comment: As a student I am asking you if you can provide some more of such examples. :)

Comment: @QuestionTheAnswer like what?  Degeneracy is good: it allows you to  optimize the choice basis states to highlight particular symmetries of the system.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero Any references please? I think my understanding in this matter is poor..

Comment: @QuestionTheAnswer For a student, I'd suggest everything revolving around the atom. The isolated hydrogen atom has highly degenerated energy levels that are useful to understand the basic structure of small atoms. Then move to Zeeman and Stark effects, both breaking symmetries and lifting degeneracies in the atom.

Comment: @QuestionTheAnswer the 3d harmonic oscillator is also a rich example.